# Using tcpdump to log blacklisted IPs

Tags: linux, scripting, tcpdump

I am using `tcpdump` to log traffic outbound on a network. I would like to be able to log traffic on a host or IP-only basis but then I would like to be able to log large numbers of potentially blacklisted IPs.

I have read about `tcpdump -F` in the `man` page that explains that I can load `tcpdump` configuration from a file, however, I cannot seem to find much in the way of documentation of how to structure this file or how to load large numbers of IPs into the filtering as I constantly get syntax errors.

How would I easily implement IP address lists with `tcpdump`?

Comment: The `-F` file should contain a filter in the syntax of libpcap: `man 7 pcap-filter`